Effective Erdős–Kac theorem
I have some number $N$ and some integer $k>0$. I want to know what fraction of numbers up to $N$ have more than $k$ prime factors. (In my application, with repetition, but the $\omega$ version is interesting too.) How can I find this?
For gigantic $N$ it's probably reasonable to estimate this with Erdős–Kac: on average numbers in this range have $\log\log N +$ $B_3$ prime factors with a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\log\log N}$ and so subtract, divide, and look up a Z-score to estimate. For tiny $N$ you can just calculate. But are there any good results for numbers in the middle?
My current application is embarrassingly small, $N\approx10^{16}$ and $k=9$, but no doubt the most interesting cases are a good deal larger.

Two quick comments: (1) $\Omega(n)$ also satisfies an Erdős–Kac theorem since it's an additive function, so at the scale where you can apply Erdős–Kac there is no need to restrict attention only to $\omega(n)$. (2) If $k$ is fixed and $N$ is large, then the count of the number of integers less than $n \leqslant N$ with $\omega(n) = k$ is well known (due to Sathe and Selberg). This latter result can be made uniform in $k$ growing as a function of $N$ (I forget the exact dependence, maybe a constant times $\log\log N$). Maybe the latter is good enough for what you want to do.

(The Sathe-Selberg result also doesn't care about the distinction between multiplicity, I think).
